# FireBreath: how can I pass dates from my plugin to Java Script

Tags: date, plugins, parameters, firebreath

I'm trying to create a simple FireBreath plugin. I need to pass a date from JavaScript to my plugin and to get date from my plugin and use it in JavaScript.

I have an idea about getting date in FB plugin from JS. I can use a FB::JSObjectPtr parameter and get it's attributes with GetAttribute.

**The main question is how to pass a date back to JS?** The only way I can find in my head is to create class DateJSAPI derived from FB::JSAPIAuto an implement all methods so JS can use instance of my class as JS Date.
I don't like such a weird way.

Can anyone advise me some good way of returning date to JS?

Comment: Pass it as a string in a known fixed format, and parse it at the other end?

Answer (score 2):

I spent several hours once trying to find a way to create Date objects in a NPAPI plugin (specifically in FireBreath) and it seems the only way to do so is to create a javascript function that returns a date object. Given that you'd have to pass a string or timestamp into said function it seems silly to do this.

If I were you I'd just send it as a timestamp (number) so you can convert it to a Date object once it gets to javascript.

Comment: I just create a class with the same interface as JS Date has and return an instance of that class.

Comment: That will work for many things, but not for all things. it is definitely one option, though